# Kentico - Add page identider/title as subject line in email link

Tags: kentico

On every page I have an email link which links to sales@domain.com. What I'd like is to add some identifier to the subject line so that sales people know from what page the email was sent (if the subject line is not edited/deleted). Although don't think page title is the best one since it's pretty long, I'm not sure what else can be used and whether it's possible. Thanks for your help!

```
<a href="mailto:sales@domain.com?subject=Website%20Inquiry: {% Some page identifier #%}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the proper link to be rendered you need to encode the output of the field.  For instance:

`<a href="{%UrlEncode("mailto:sales@domain.com?subject=Website%20Inquiry:" + CurrentDocument.DocumentName)#%}">Click here</a>`

You can also use a specific page field like so:

`CurrentDocument.GetValue("YourColumnName")`

So if you added a new field specifically for the subject, it could be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following if you'd like:

```
{% CurrentDocument.DocumentName #%} (ex: "Our Company")

{% CurrentDocument.DocumentNamePath #%} (ex: "/About/About Us/Our Company")
```

It depends how detailed you want to be, but you can get any info from the page that you want by using the macro.